# Php don't send empty value

Tags: php, post, mysqli

I've created a code that updates an Sql entry, but when you leave an value blank, it removes the existing value.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "HahahNo";
$dbname = "DATA";
$id = $_POST["id"];
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id=$id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Is there any way not to clear the not filled in values? Im fairly new to php.

Comment: store the values in session

Comment: Paste you code here. No one will go to third-party sites

Comment: Paste your code here.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for the tip, I did not know how to do that.

Comment: I've done it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `$_POST` contains values.

First check if `$_POST` value has been set with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (has been posted).

Then check if the string isn't empty with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
if (!isset($_POST['firstname'] || strlen($_POST['firstname']) == 0) {
    echo 'Please enter first name';
} else {
    // Do your DB update
}
```

**Edit**: Naturally [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is better because you only need one check to do:

```
if (empty($_POST['firstname']) {
    echo 'Please enter first name';
} ...
```

Thanks to @Fred -ii-

**Edit II**: As pointed out by @alex

```
if ($_POST['firstname']) {
    echo 'Please enter first name';
} ...
```

would work too. Explained in [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: why not use `if($_POST['firstname']) ` ?

Comment: @alex because an empty string would return true too. The `$_POST['first_name']` is set but empty

Comment: @Daenu empty string would return false NOT true as denoted [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is *validation* of user-supplied data. You're right - a user who hasn't read the instructions of your form could cause unintended data loss. Additionally a [malicious user](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) or [innocent child](https://xkcd.com/327/) could cause more harm with SQL injection.

First check your field meets minimum requirements. You could validate email addresses, postcodes, phone numbers, URLs... but to answer your question Daenu's answer is perfect.

Once you are satisfied the data meets your databases' requirements, check it is safe. Strip it of any malicious SQL commands. You can use prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi.

Also think about the specification of the data. Is the data type of each field a string or integer or float? What character set is your web page in (UTF-8 is a safe choice) and therefore what character set does your data arrive with? Does your database match (UTF8MB4 is a good companion)?

Comment: You've got some solid points there, However, I would say that to prevent SQL-injection, the only *real* way would be to use prepared statements (OPs even using MySQLi - so he can do that, your example has the outdated `mysql_`).

Comment: Thanks @Qirel I updated the answer to remove `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 1):

You can write condition before execute function,

```
//all values are not null then update is perform
    if(!is_null($firstname) && !is_null($lastname) &&  !is_null($email)){
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Success";
      } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
      }
    }
```